# Html title is not displaying in a struts2 deployed on tomcat server

Tags: html, tomcat, struts2, title

I tried many ways but html title is not displaying in struts2 application. A simple code like this

```
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
```

I am not sure is the problem with tomcat server or Struts2. Can you help on this.

Comment: You haven't provided nearly enough information to help you. Do some debugging, look through your logs, figure out what's up and revise your question accordingly. As it is currently, it will be closed or down voted heavily.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your html code can not be supported by the newest browsers. you could use the w3c validator http://validator.w3.org/ to test if your code has the error.

Comment: I tried code without deploying on tomcat server.I can see the title in firebug.same code if I deploy on tomcat I am not seeing the title.